# Validate an XML against XSD with imports using C#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I need to validate an XML documents against a set of XSD schemas. There is a top-level schema which imports other schemas, nested schemas may also import some schemas. For example, schema a.xsd imports b.xsd and c.xsd; b.xsd imports d.xsd. In this example a.xsd is a top-level schema.

I use the following code for a such validaton:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document;
        settings.Schemas.Add("targetNs", "path/to/a.xsd");
        settings.ValidationEventHandler += ValidateHandler;

        var reader = XmlReader.Create("path/to/file.xml", settings);
        while (reader.Read()) ;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

private static void ValidateHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Although the code above implicity uses nested schemas for a valuidation, there is a problem: if some nested schema is invalid XML document it is just ignored without any exceptions.

Could you please help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to validate the schema(s) before validating the document you can do it as follows:

```
try
{
    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead("path/to/a.xsd"))
    {
        XmlSchema schema = XmlSchema.Read(fs, ValidateHandler);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new Exception("Schema file is invalid. " + e.Message);
}
```

Then add the schema to your settings as follows:

```
schema.TargetNamespace = "targetNs";
settings.Schemas.Addschema(schema);
```